# How do I create, from a tuple of fractions, a new tuple with their decimal values?

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, indices

I have a tuple of fractions:

```
data = (-17/7, 5/14, -11/14)
```

I want an additional tuple with their decimal equivalents:

```
(-2.43, 0.36, -0.79)
```

This will work:

```
print((round(float(data[0]),2),  


round(float(data[1]),2),


round(float(data[2]),2)))
```

but I would like something more concise.  I tried this list comprehension (which I can turn into a tuple later):

```
data1 = [round(float(data[i]),2) for i in data]
```

but got this error message:  tuple indices must be integers or slices, not Rational

Tried many Python searches but no one seems to address this problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error you got, it points to where you're using indices:

```
data1 = [round(float(data[i]),2) for i in data]
```

The problem is in `data[i]`,  since you're using `i` as an index.

As the error states, `i` is not an integer.

Here, you really want `i`

To get the results you want, you can edit your code to this:

```
data1 = (* [round(float(i), 2) for i in data], )
```

Note: The `*` is used to unpack the items out of the list